# adding action listener to a button in netbeans

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, jbutton, actionlistener

How to add an action listener to a button in netbeans

I tried to do that, but I don't know how

```
button.addactionlistener(null);
```

Comment: The same way you add it in Eclipse and any other IDE. (Java is case sensitive, *addactionlistener* is different from *addActionListener*)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need to implement action listener in your class.

```
public class YourProject extends JFrame implements ActionListener{
yourbutton.addActionListener(this);
```

The you need to add the override method.

I hope this helps you.

Answer (score 1):

YOu can also add by another way

```
JButton jb= new JButton("ok");

jb.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae)
      {System.out.println("You have clicked ok button");
    }
});
```